# MATLAB Shift the origin (0,0) of the pixels in my image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, shift

As an input of my code, I need to have some positions on my picture: the positions are in pixels and the origin (0,0) is in the CORNER top left of my picture

[image: picture where positions are tracked with origin top left]

The problem is that when I run my code which maps the positions on my picture, the origin shifts to the bottom left :

[image: picture where positions are mapped with origin bottom left]

So my question is : how could I also shift my input (positions of my picture1) so that it is relevant with the code process?

Thank you for your help,
Aude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With images you reverse the Y axis:

```
set(ax,'YDir','reverse');
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer with a bit detail:

In computers, image processing etc it is the norm to have the (0,0) pixel in the top left corner. However, it is understandable that when you have `x`,`y` data, you'd want to plot it *together* with the image. Here some solutions:

```
imshow(image);
axis xy; % This line sets up the axis in a standard coordinate system
```

you can revert it with `axis ij`

---

Often, this is not enough. As `imshow` assumes that each pixel is in integer index position, and you may not have that. Maybe your data is in milimeters, or in any other arbitrary units. A solution to that is using `imagesc`

```
imagesc(img);
```

is equivalent to `imashow(img);axis xy`. Additionally, you can choose arbitrary matrices for pixel locations as `imagesc(x,y,img)`;

---

Finally, you can `flipud` your data for plotting, but I suggest you do that inline with the plot, so you dont modify the data itself.

```
imshow(flipud(img))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on your code. Maybe you can do it on-the-fly so you'll get the desired output right away.

If not just flip the output. You could use `flipud` for that.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html